# Can Apple Macintosh computers boot from a USB volume?

Tags: macos, mac, usb, boot, intel-mac

Can I attach a USB external drive to a Mac and boot from it?

Specifically, will I be able to install Snow Leopard from an external USB DVD drive on a modern Intel Macbook?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**Mac 101: Yes, Intel Macs can be booted from an external USB drive**](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/12/18/mac-101-yes-intel-macs-can-be-booted-from-an-external-usb-drive/)

> Since the release of the Intel Mac computers, and with Mac OS X 10.4.5 or later, you can start up from an installed system on a USB hard disk. Here's the [Apple support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1948) that tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Right, and it seems to work as well as any firewire volume I have used, too. I have a USB volume where I run a full clone backup (using SuperDuper, highly recommended) and I occasionally boot from this to test that my backups are good.